# Reuse function results in LINQ

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query in LINQ as an example.  Is it possible to save the results of the GetCalendarResources function so I wouldn't have to call it more than once? Thanks.

```
var query = from T in query2.AsEnumerable()
            select new Event
            {
               resource = GetCalendarResources(T.eventID),
               text = GetCalendarResources(T.eventID) + T.eventName
            };
```

Comment: This query is highly inefficient. You are doing n+1 database calls and there is no filtering.

Comment: This isn't an actual query I am using. I just wrote it up as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) keyword, which gives you the liberty to use its value for the next level:

```
var query = from T in query2.AsEnumerable()
            let res= GetCalendarResources(T.eventID)
            select new Event
            {
               resource =res,
               text = res + T.eventName
            };
```

Comment: Thanks.  Worked great.  I've used it in the past but I forgot about it.